# Find/Select products with duplicate attributes

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this:

```
products_stock_id   products_id   products_stock_attributes   products_stock_quantity
11                    65                1-3                     3
12                    65                1-8                     4
13                    65                1-10                    3
14                    66                1-8                     0
15                    66                1-3                     1
16                    66                1-8                     7
17                    66                1-12                    6
18                    66                1-13                    21
19                    67                1-7                     12
20                    68                1-8                     0
21                    68                1-10                    7
21                    69                1-3                     3
22                    69                1-8                     4
23                    69                1-10                    3
24                    69                1-8                     0
25                    69                1-3                     1
26                    70                1-8                     7
27                    71                1-12                    6
28                    71                1-13                    2
29                    72                1-7                     11
30                    72                1-8                     10
31                    72                1-14                    6
```

I am trying to find all the products_id that have 1-8 (in products_stock_attributes) more than once.
The table above has products_id 66 and 69 with 1-8 occurring more than once.
How can I get the results using MySQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT products_id
FROM yourtable
WHERE products_stock_attributes = '1-8' 
GROUP BY products_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```